# How do I round up a float whose mantissa is ending in 5?

Tags: perl, rounding

I want to round up a floating-point number. For example, `sprintf '%.4f', 0.12345` returns `0.1235` and `sprintf '%.4f', 0.12325` returns `0.1232`. For the second example, I want it to print out `0.1233`, not `0.1232`.

`sprintf` in Perl is not good enough. [`Math::BigFloat`](http://p3rl.org/Math%3a%3aBigFloat) can do it, but it’s a little over-kill.

Does anyone know if there is other effective way to round up, or whether there is any other module in Perl?

Comment: Why do you want to introduce bias into your code?  You do not want to have 4 digits produce the floor and 5 digits produce the ceiling, because that is unbalanced toward the ceiling. You need 4 go one way, 4 go the other way, the the middle one to flipflop every other time. Which is exactly what Perl does.

Answer (score 1):

The exact way `sprintf` will round a number is dependent on how the system libraries round numbers. If you need to control exactly how a number is rounded you will need to use a library that implements your desired rounding explicitly, or write a function to round as desired.

For example to round a positive number to an arbitrary precision, where 5 rounds up this would work.

```
sub round {
    my $numer     = shift;
    my $precision = shift;
    return int($numer * 10 ** $precision + 0.5) * 10 ** -$precision;
}
```

This however doesn't round correctly for negative numbers, -0.12324 incorrectly rounds to -0.1231. A solution where 5 should round up (that is towards positive infinity) would be to use `floor` instead of `int`.

```
use POSIX qw(floor);
sub round {
    my $numer     = shift;
    my $precision = shift;
    return floor($numer * 10 ** $precision + 0.5) * 10 ** -$precision;
}
```

If instead 5 should round to the largest absolute value (that is round away from 0) then you can add a simple check for negative numbers to round them in the correct direction.

```
sub round {
    my $numer     = shift;
    my $precision = shift;
    my $direction = $numer >= 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5;
    return int($numer * 10 ** $precision + $direction) * 10 ** -$precision;
}
```

There are more complex rules for rounding used in some circumstances where the bias from rounding 5 in one direction for all numbers is unacceptable and any (decimal) rounding of floating point numbers is subject to possible errors due to imprecision in their binary format.

Comment: thanks for you answer. but it still print out 0.1232, not what I want.

Comment: @amyxu, what did you try? For all three functions I provided round(0.12325, 4) == 0.1233

Answer (score 1):

Perl's `sprintf` can only be as good as the data it's fed.
There is no floating point number equal exact to either 0.12345 or 0.12325:

- The floating point number closest to the 0.12345 is exactly `2223877495995551/2**54` ≈ 0.1234**5**0000000000004, a value slightly greater than the input.
- The floating point number closest to the 0.12325 is exactly `4440549232587309/2**55` ≈ 0.1232**4**9999999999998, a value slightly less than the input.

Note that the 5th decimal digit of the latter one is 4 not 5.
When rounded to 4 decimal places under the usual rules, they *must* come out as 0.1235 and 0.1232 respectively.

You say that using `Math::BigFloat` is a little overkill, but it seems that what you really want is decimal arithmetic so the overkill is inescapable.

Answer (score 0):

This did work for me:

```
print sprintf '%.*f', 4, 0.12325
```

Your code does work for me too. Did you test that code on its own?
Could you tell us your perl version too (`perl -v`)?

Comment: Funny enough, both your solution and the `#2` of the OP produced the same output for me: `0.1233` on `Perl 5.12.4` MSWin32-x86-multi-thread Activeperl on a 32bit WinXP machine.

Comment: For me too, I edited my answer. Iam using `5.14.2` Activeperl MSWin32-x86-multi-thread too.

Comment: On Linux, sprintf always rounds toward even on a 5 at the end.

Comment: @Brainbot, My perl version is v5.8.8. I just tried your solution. it didn't work for me. :(

Comment: @amyxu Try updating perl and run your code again, the most recent version is `5.16`